# Opacity seems to work when only its value is 1

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey I am trying to make a color picker with some div elements and I have a problem with getting to understand opacity.

This is my HTML:

```
<form>
    <label for="red">RED</label>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="255" step="1" value="0" id="red" name="red" onchange="changeColors()">
    <label for="green">Green</label>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="255" step="1" value="0" id="green" name="green" onchange="changeColors()">
    <label for="blue">Blue</label>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="255" step="1" value="0" id="blue" name="blue" onchange="changeColors()">
    <label for="opacity">Alpha</label>
    <input type="text" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="1" id="opacity" name="opacity" onchange="changeColors()">
</form>
<div id="div"><div>
```

My current script:

```
function changeColors() {
    //get the numbers from the html
    var rd = parseInt(document.getElementById("red").value);
    var gr = parseInt(document.getElementById("green").value);
    var bl = parseInt(document.getElementById("blue").value);
    var op = parseInt(document.getElementById("opacity").value);

    //convert the decimal into hexadecimal

    var rdhex = (rd < 16) ? "0" + rd.toString(16) : rd.toString(16);
    var grhex = (gr < 16) ? "0" + gr.toString(16) : gr.toString(16);
    var blhex = (bl < 16) ? "0" + bl.toString(16) : bl.toString(16);

    //concatenate all hex to ger a color
    var hexcode = "#" + rdhex + grhex + blhex;

    //view the change in the browser
    document.getElementById("div").style.backgroundColor = hexcode;
    //change opacity
    document.getElementById("div").style.opacity = op;
}
```

The [**jsBin**](http://jsbin.com/UtUdEtU/1/)

As you can see only when the opacity is "1" I can see any results. The moment you try to change the value to 0.5 for example the whole imagery disappears.

What is wrong with it?

Comment: Opacity is a decimal value and your are doing `parseInt` over it when it is retrieved

Comment: @ Henry: *"Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — **in the question itself**. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance."* Links to off-site live sites like JSBin or jsFiddle are a nice *adjunct*, not a replacement, for doing that. François Wahl was kind enough to copy your code into your question for you.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I will have this is mind. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're parsing to an int so "0.5" will round to 0.

Use parseFloat instead:

```
parseFloat(document.getElementById("opacity").value);
```

Comment: Yea this is correct, also just a side info, you might like to check `rgba` instead of using `opacity` property.

Answer (score 2):

When you change the opacity to 0.5 the actual CSS that is set is `opacity: 0;`.

I think you want to parse the value as a float.